# Invalid column name on Having in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have quick question why I can't use having keyword on distance? I need somehow to check is distance < 20 for example

```
SELECT 
    Id, Lat, Lng,
    (6367 * acos( cos( radians(45.444) )
      * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Lng ) - radians(158.554) )
      + sin( radians(4545) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM 
    Posts
HAVING 
    distance < 15  // Invalid column Name 
ORDER BY 
    distance
```

Comment: You mean `WHERE`? `HAVING` is only relevant for groups in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You can use `where` or just use `(6367 * acos( cos( radians(45.444) )
      * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Lng ) - radians(158.554) )
      + sin( radians(4545) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) )` in `HAVING`

Comment: You can't use an Alias in a HAVING or WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Id, Lat, Lng,
         (6367 * acos(cos(radians(45.444)) * cos(radians(Lat)) * 
          cos(radians(Lng) - radians(158.554)) + sin(radians(4545)) * 
          sin(radians(Lat)))) AS distance 
     FROM Posts) p
WHERE 
    p.distance < 15  
ORDER BY 
    p.distance
```

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest `outer apply` for this purpose:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Lat, p.Lng, d.distance
FROM Posts p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT (6367 * acos( cos( radians(45.444) )
             * cos( radians( p.Lat ) ) * cos( radians( p.Lng ) - radians(158.554) )
             + sin( radians(4545) ) * sin( radians( p.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
     ) d
FROM Posts p
WHERE d.distance < 15 
ORDER BY distance;
```

The use of `HAVING` as a substitute for `WHERE` is an extension for MySQL.  In other databases, you can use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join (which is the technical name for what `APPLY` does).  In this case, I think the lateral join is convenient, because it separates the logic for this quite complicated formula.

Answer (score -2):

YOu can use brackets to dictate you mean a field name not a pereserved keyword:

```
SELECT Id,Lat,Lng,(6367 * acos( cos( radians(45.444) )
      * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Lng ) - radians(158.554) )
      + sin( radians(4545) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Posts
       HAVING [distance] < 15  // Invalid column Name 
       ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: no still doesnt work,  Invalid column name 'distance'

Comment: Have you checked the spelling? Are you sure that the column exist?

Comment: I read your code now... you don't have the Group By Clause and that causes the problem not the name